# Matlab table, column with different sized elements

Tags: matlab

I want to add to my table a column with numerical vectors of different length. Is that possible?

I really want to keep this data in the same table with the rest.

I'm trying to add column 'f'. Example:

```
 A =

    id          name          length          f

    1           'A'           80           [8 , 9 , 10]
    2           'B'           100          [1]
    3           'C'           5            [10, 500, -1, 2, 3, 4]
```

etc.

I might end up creating a large, NaN filled vector for each row, and replace them with the values I need, but that is a very ugly solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `f = {8:10; 1; [10, 500, -1, 2:4]};`, then

```
A = table(f);
```

should give you what you need. Or, if `A` is already defined, `A.f = f`.

Note that when accessing the data you have to use cell indexing to retrieve a vector of doubles, for example `A.f{2}` will return `1`.

Comment: I ended up making a struct array to be converted into a table later, but your answer is a lot better. Thanks!